# expand hostnames to fqdn before calling ssh?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh

I make use of an .ssh/config file to set my username appropriately based on a given portion of a subdomain, e.g.

```
Host *widgetshop.com*
   User foobar
   ControlMaster auto
   ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%p

Host *
   ControlMaster auto
   ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%p
```

This works if I write:

```
ssh foo.widgetshop.com
```

but does not work if I were to write:

```
ssh foo
```

which upon search path resolution becomes the same fqdn.

Anyone have a way to expand shortnames before calling ssh, or an alternative approach?

Comment: Does setting `CanonicalizeHostname` to `yes` solve the problem? It does not change how `ssh` is called but changes what part of the config is applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the `host` command:

```
ssh $(host -t A  foo | cut -f1 -d" ")
```

Put that into a shell script (replace "foo" with "$1") and exec ssh.

Comment: This is what I will likely end up doing. Was just hoping someone had something a bit slicker than me doing an ssh alias. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I actually make custom launchers with some part that looks like `ssh myname@myhost.widgetshop.com`.

Answer (score 12):

As of OpenSSH 6.5, you can do this with the `CanonicalizeHostname` option in ssh_config. Here's an example that should do what you want:

```
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains widgetshop.com

Host *.widgetshop.com
     User foobar
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The ssh_config manpage answers this:

> The host is the hostname argument given on the command line (i.e. the name is not converted to a canonicalized host name before matching).

In other words, it doesn't work because it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Quite aware, thanks. Was hoping for a preexisting ssh alias/function/wrapper or the like.

Answer (score -1):

please see my "alternative approach")

```
mbp:~ alexus$ grep f9 /etc/hosts
XX.XXX.XX.XXX   f9
mbp:~ alexus$ ssh f9 hostname
f9.XXX.org
mbp:~ alexus$
```

Comment: Don't think you understood the problem. I want the hostname fully expanded BEFORE calling ssh. This does not do so, nor would putting a million entries in /etc/hosts be a solution.

Comment: Cramming stuff into `/etc/hosts` is almost *UNIVERSALLY* the wrong solution.